# IE 11 slowness in downloading http response

Tags: performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

i am developing an Angular 4 application. One of the HTTP requests returns a large amount of data - approximately 15 MB. I have noticed that downloading that takes more than 20 seconds on IE11 (sometimes more than 35 seconds); whereas on Chrome it happens under 500ms.
I copied the http response to local .json files and tried pointing my code to those.
The result is the same.
Please see attached screenshots.

[image: Comparison of IE11 timings and Chrome]
[image: IE11 network tab Timings]

Moreover, if i debug with Fiddler, I see that Fiddler receives the response nearly 20 seconds before code in IE is invoked. See below. It shows that the alert "mapper invoked" gets called 20 seconds after ClientDoneResponse in Fiddler.
[image: Fiddler comparison]

Any idea why IE11 is taking so long whereas Chrome finishes in a few milliseconds?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am not able to create one because I am not able to upload a large enough JSON file to any site which i can then download in my plunk.

Comment: Show your code, the code that you use to download the file.